# How to prove the following proposition about positive semi-definiteness?

Tags: matrices, positive-semidefinite

If the real symmetric matrix

$$M=  \begin{bmatrix}
    \alpha & \textbf{q}^T  \\
    \textbf{q} & N
  \end{bmatrix}
$$
is positive semidefinite with $\alpha > 0$, then the matrix
$$N-\frac 1 \alpha \textbf{q} \textbf{q}^T$$ is also positive semidefinite.

This form reminds me of determinant and the fact that a matrix is PSD *iff* leading principal minors is non-negative. But I have no idea how to prove the proposition precisely.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement#Schur_complement_condition_for_positive_definiteness_and_positive_semidefiniteness

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. I almost forgot this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prove that
$$x^T \left(N-\dfrac1{\alpha}qq^T\right)x \geq 0$$
for all $x$. We know that since $M$ is positive semidefinite, $y^TMy \geq $ for all $y$. Now take $y=\begin{bmatrix}\beta\\x\end{bmatrix}$, where $\beta$ is a scalar such that
$$y^TMy = x^T \left(N-\dfrac1{\alpha}qq^T\right)x$$

Comment: How to show such $\beta$ exists?

Comment: Why don't you multiply out and see what $\beta$ should be? It will turn out to be $-q^Tx/\alpha$.